# creating a json array in python

Tags: python, json

I need to create a json array like `["a", "b", "c", "d"]`

I'm trying to create it as follows

```
import json

with open('djs.json', 'w') as outfile:
    for dj in DJ.objects.all():
        json.dump(str(dj), outfile, separators=(',', ': '))
```

This creates something like `"a","b","c","d"`

What would be the correct way to do this?

Comment: What is `DJ.objects.all()` ?

Comment: `DJ.objects` are objects of my Django model.

Comment: What does it contain?

Comment: `dj` is a Django model object that contains all the information regarding a DJ. `dj` evaluates to the DJ name if that's what you are asking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about this:

```
lst = [str(dj) for dj in DJ.objects.all()]    
with open('data.txt', 'w+') as outfile:
    json.dump(lst, outfile)
```

if your `__unicode__` is a single field, You could even do

```
json_dump = json.dump(list(Dj.objects.values_list('field', flat=True)))
```

Comment: This is giving me a blank json file for some reason.

Comment: do you want to return a json to a respond to a request ?

Comment: No, I need to make a JSON file with a JSON array containing the name of all the DJs.

Comment: Ok. check the edit. You should have the json in a file called `data.txt`